# regular expression not start with zero and be in a specified limit

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a Regular expression that will not start with zero and be in a specified limit, say upto 7 digit long

Valid Example:

```
100,
2345678,
```

Invalid Example:

```
01,
0256,
12345678
```

I tried the following

pattern:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{1,7}$
```

But this not help

Comment: `^[1-9][0-9]{0,6}$`, please note `0` and `6`: mandatory first digit (`[1-9]`) followed by optionally ones (up to 6) so we have up to `7` digits in total

Comment: Is the comma at the end of the lines is part of the string

Comment: @Slkrasnodar end of the lines

Comment: Re: "But this not help": Why not? Please be specific about why it doesn't work, because that will be relevant to fixing it.

Comment: @ruakh I saw that question you mentioned but that didnt solve my problem my question is different from the question you mentioned, on that question user have to enter exactly 7 digit always eg:1 is invalid ,  here the maximum limit is 7 digits for eg; 1  is valid here

Comment: @Mussammil: I didn't mention any question. (The messaging is confusing; I don't know why they do it that way. I voted to close your question as "needs more details", and then Wiktor Stribiżew closed your question as a duplicate, so the system shows both our usernames but only his reason.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, this should work: `^[1-9][0-9]{0,6}$`

Comment: It Worked like a charm

Comment: Some explanation would be useful.

Comment: @Gurinder its worked thanks

Comment: with ^ we are saying start must be with 1-9 and next characters can be 0-9 and then their length should be between 0-6, in other work max 7 characters. $ mean end of string

Answer (score 2):

try to below way it's working

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,6}$
```

Comment: drop `*`; `{0, 6}` is enough

Comment: @Bansi29 invalid regular expression got an error